# ArrayList skipping some data while adding data in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Well I am running a loop to get data...it get's all the data of the month June..but when it comes to 19-June-2019 it skips the record and moves further without adding data into ArrayList.

My code

```
        this.connection = createConnection();

        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();

        Calendar last_month_data = Calendar.getInstance();
        last_month_data.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
        n=last_month_data.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        String last_month_year = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM- 
        yyyy").format(last_month_data.getTime());

        String month_name = lastMonth.getText().toString();

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            String date = i + "-" + last_month_year;

            ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("Select 
            ATTN_TYPE,TO_CHAR(ATTN_TIME,'HH24:MI'),REMARK from MATTN_MAS 
            where ATTN_DATE='" + date + "' and Username='" + Username + "' 
            ORDER BY TRAN_NO DESC");

            String Attn_Type;

            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            Date d=format.parse(date);

            SimpleDateFormat fomat1=new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
            String weekName=fomat1.format(d);

            StringBuffer myweekDate=new StringBuffer(weekName+", "+date);
            String weekDate=myweekDate.toString();

            if (resultSet.next()) {
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    Attn_Type = resultSet.getString(1);
                    String Time = resultSet.getString(2);
                    String Reason = resultSet.getString(3);

                    if (Attn_Type.equals("I")) {
                        String Attn_Type_In = "In";
                        String Attn_Type_Out = null;

                  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("" + i);
                   String date_no = stringBuilder.toString();

                   myOptions.add(new Attendance_Data(Attn_Type_In,  
                   weekDate, Reason, i, date_no, month_name,Time));

                    } else{
                        String Attn_Type_Out = "Out";
                        String Attn_Type_In = null;
                  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("" + i);
                  String date_no = stringBuilder.toString();

                  myOptions.add(new Attendance_Data(Attn_Type_Out,  
                  weekDate, Reason, i, date_no, month_name,Time));
                    }
                }
            }else {
                Attn_Type = "Absent";
                String out = null;
                String Reason=null;
                String Time=null;

                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("" + i);
                String date_no = stringBuilder.toString();

                myOptions.add(new Attendance_Data(Attn_Type, weekDate,
                Reason, i, date_no, month_name,Time));
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("My Error"+e);
    }
}
```

I want all the data of June from date 1 to date 30 but if there are no records of the given date it should insert Absent in ArrayList, Above code is working fine for all the date but the problem is it is not adding data for 19-Jun-2019 in ArrayList even no error is been shown I am not getting what exactly the problem is please help me out.

[Please Check this Screenshot for more details...after Thursday,20 it skips 19, Wednesday and displaying data for Tuesday](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CL5uO.png)

Comment: Is there any data for that date? Also, is the data latter to 19-Jun showing?

Comment: Yes there is data for 19 June...

Comment: is the data latter to 19-Jun showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Ok I got the answer thanks...
We have to use do....while instead of just while....it was 
just skipping single data each time.....bcoz while is not 
going to check second time if data is available or not....below is 
the code...
.
  if (resultSet.next()) {
    do {
          Attn_Type = resultSet.getString(1);
          String Time = resultSet.getString(2);
          String Reason = resultSet.getString(3);

   if (Attn_Type.equals("I")) {
       String Attn_Type_In = "In";
       String Attn_Type_Out = null;

     StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("" + i);
     String date_no = stringBuilder.toString();

      myOptions.add(new Attendance_Data(Attn_Type_In, 
      weekDate, Reason, i, date_no, month_name, Time));

    } else {
     String Attn_Type_Out = "Out";
     String Attn_Type_In = null;
     StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("" + i);
     String date_no = stringBuilder.toString();

         myOptions.add(new Attendance_Data(Attn_Type_Out, 
         weekDate, Reason, i, date_no, month_name, Time));
        }
      } while (resultSet.next());
  } else {
     Attn_Type = "Absent";
     String out = null;
     String Reason = null;
     String Time = null;
     StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("" + i);
     String date_no = stringBuilder.toString();             

     myOptions.add(new Attendance_Data(Attn_Type, weekDate, 
     Reason, i, date_no, month_name, Time));
      }
    }
  }
```

[..Output of above code is in below image..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7f0U.png)